# Convert raster time series of multiple GeoTIFF images to NetCDF

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, rasterio

I have a raster time series stored in multiple `GeoTIFF` files (`*.tif`) that I'd like to convert to a single `NetCDF` file.   The data is `uint16`.

I could probably use `gdal_translate` to convert each image to netcdf using:

```
 gdal_translate -of netcdf -co FORMAT=NC4 20150520_0164.tif foo.nc
```

and then some scripting with `NCO` to extract dates from filenames and then concatenate, but I was wondering whether I might do this more effectively in Python using `xarray` and it's new `rasterio` backend.

I can read a file easily:

```
import glob
import xarray as xr
f = glob.glob('*.tif')
da = xr.open_rasterio(f[0]) 
da
```

which returns

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 5490, x: 5490)>
[30140100 values with dtype=uint16]
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int64 1
  * y        (y) float64 5e+05 5e+05 5e+05 5e+05 5e+05 4.999e+05 4.999e+05 ...
  * x        (x) float64 8e+05 8e+05 8e+05 8e+05 8.001e+05 8.001e+05 ...
Attributes:
    crs:      +init=epsg:32620
```

and I can write one of these to NetCDF:

```
ds.to_netcdf('foo.nc')
```

but ideally I would be able to use something like `xr.open_mfdataset` , write the time values (extracted from the filenames) and then write the entire aggregation to `netCDF`. And have `dask` handle the out-of-core memory issues. :-)

Can something like this be done with `xarray` and `dask`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xarray should be able to do the concat step for you. I have adapted your example a bit below. It will be up to you to parse the filenames into something useful.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

def time_index_from_filenames(filenames):
    '''helper function to create a pandas DatetimeIndex
       Filename example: 20150520_0164.tif'''
    return pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp(f[:8]) for f in filenames])

filenames = glob.glob('*.tif')
time = xr.Variable('time', time_index_from_filenames(filenames))
chunks = {'x': 5490, 'y': 5490, 'band': 1}
da = xr.concat([xr.open_rasterio(f, chunks=chunks) for f in filenames], dim=time)
```

Comment: this works great -- and now that I've read the open_rasterio documentation at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_rasterio.html I understand that providing the chunks argument loads the data into a dask array.

Comment: Great. Glad it worked out for you. Something like this would probably be a good recipe here: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/auto_gallery/index.html

Comment: Hi @RichSignell would you mind to share your script with me? I have monthly precipitation data in GeoTIFF from 1981 and would like to convert it into single NetCDF with time dimension enabled.