# renaming __xarray_dataarray_variable__ in xarray dataarray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have created a xarray dataarray using the xarray concat command. This has resulted in a dataarray with name `__xarray_dataarray_variable__`. However, I cannot seem to rename it using the `rename` command. Is there some other way to rename it?

I tried this:

```
da.rename({'__xarray_dataarray_variable__': 'new'})
```

but I get this error: `*** ValueError: cannot rename '__xarray_dataarray_variable__' because it is not a variable or dimension in this dataset`

This is what the dataarray looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 2, band: 1, y: 2334, x: 4258)>
dask.array<shape=(2, 1, 2334, 4258), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 1, 2334, 4258)>
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int32 1
  * y        (y) float64 4.406e+06 4.406e+06 4.406e+06 4.406e+06 4.406e+06 ...
  * x        (x) float64 1.125e+05 1.126e+05 1.127e+05 1.128e+05 1.129e+05 ...
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2005-12-31 2006-12-31
Attributes:
    transform:   (90.0, 0.0, 112500.0, 0.0, -90.0, 4406400.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    crs:         +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs +proj=utm +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +unit...
    res:         (90.0, 90.0)
    is_tiled:    1
    nodatavals:  (-9999.0,)
```

From http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.to_netcdf.html, Only xarray.Dataset objects can be written to netCDF files, so the xarray.DataArray is converted to a xarray.Dataset object containing a single variable. If the DataArray has no name, or if the name is the same as a co-ordinate name, then it is given the name ‘**xarray_dataarray_variable**’.

Comment: does `da.name = 'new'` do the trick? None of the coordinates/dimensions in your DataArray have the `__xarray_dataarray_variable__` name.

Comment: thanks @jhamman, I get this error when I do `da.name = 'new'`  `*** AttributeError: cannot set attribute '__xarray_dataarray_variable__' on a 'DataArray' object. Use __setitem__ style assignment (e.g., `ds['name'] = ...`) instead to assign variables.`

Comment: @jhamman, if it helps I am using your code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899337/convert-raster-time-series-of-multiple-geotiff-images-to-netcdf to create a netCDF file from a bunch of raster files

Comment: okay, I see. I was off in my initial suggestion. Can you convert your DataArray to a Dataset: `da.to_dataset(name='new')`?

Comment: thanks @jhamman, this works! can you add this as answer so I can accept?

Comment: How did you create the DataArray `da`? It doesn't have any name set, or you would see it in the repr, e.g., `<xarray.DataArray '__xarray_dataarray_variable__' ...>`.

Comment: @shoyer, thanks for a great package! I created it from a bunch of rasters using the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899337/convert-raster-time-series-of-multiple-geotiff-images-to-netcdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `to_dataset` method:

```
ds = da.to_dataset(name='new')
```