# How to create a netcdf file from the multiple raster files in python?

Tags: python, tiff, netcdf, python-xarray

There are many raster files with `tiff` format. Each raster file represents hourly temperature. The files name represent the time series from `2018-1-1 01:00:00` to `2018-1-30 23:00:00` and their names show the specific time of the temperature (for example : file_2018-01-01_01_temp.tiff). 
I used the answer of the already question: [Convert raster time series of multiple GeoTIFF images to NetCDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899337/convert-raster-time-series-of-multiple-geotiff-images-to-netcdf).But I reprieved the `ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp` error. Is it possible to convert all of them to one `netcdf` file in python?

some example files:
[1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ln6tvym7own90c/file_2018-01-01_03_temp.tiff?dl=0) [2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ln6tvym7own90c/file_2018-01-01_03_temp.tiff?dl=0)

Comment: xarray's `xr.open_rasterio` seems to work well with your example TIFF file, so combined with xarray's `to_netcdf`, that should make the conversion fairly simple.

Comment: Hi @Bart and @EdChum, I tried the example with the question already has an answer  `Convert raster time series of multiple GeoTIFF images to NetCDF`. I renamed my file to `20150520_0164.tif`, but there is `ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp` error! I am using python 3.7.

Comment: it is best to either update your question (if it is no longer a duplicate, it can be re-opened), or ask a new question. It's difficult to see exactly where it goes wrong from just that error message...